# Why does the shift key only affect the first subsequent character?

Tags: keyboard, kinesis-advantage, sticky-keys

On my Kinesis Advantage (kb500) keyboard, whenever I hold down the left shift key and type letters, it only capitalizes the first character, and then the rest are unaffected by the shift key.

I looked into the sticky keys setting in windows but did not find any enabled settings that might affect this behavior.

Resetting the keyboard to factory defaults seemed to fix it but I would like to know how to avoid this in the future...since it seems that it was something I did on the keyboard itself to set it up this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [original (KB500) manual](https://kinesis-ergo.com/wp-content/uploads/kb500-user_manual.pdf), this is a sticky-key feature of the keyboard itself, rather than the OS.

> Sticky keys feature for Ctrl, Alt, and Shift (Progrm + modifier + F6)
>
> A “sticky” modifier key may be useful because it doesn’t need to be held down when
>   performing an awkward combination of keys. Once tapped, a sticky key is active until a nonmodifier key is pressed and released. In fact two sticky modifiers keys can be tapped in
>   sequence before pressing the key to be modified.
>
> In general, Kinesis recommends this feature be set in your operating system. With the Kinesis
>   on-board sticky keys feature, if you prefer to occasionally hold down the "sticky modifier,"
>   only the first keystroke that follows is modified, whereas operating system versions of "sticky
>   keys" will continue to modify until the sticky modifier is released.
>
> To turn on or off the “on-board programmability” version of sticky keys, press and hold the
>   Progrm key, add the modifier key to be made sticky, and finally tap F6. To make a modifier
>   “non-sticky,” repeat this process or perform a total memory reset.

Pressing `Left-Shift`+`Progrm`+`F6` in this case would specifically solve (but also create!) this issue.

Comment: This didn't work for me: sticky keys means when you press shift, you can release it and it's as though shift is held down. My issue (and the one described in the original question), is that when shift *is* held down, only the first character is capitalized. As an example: This was typed with shift held for the whole sentence. IF I TURN STICKY KEYS ON AND RELEASE SHIFT< THIS IS WHAT I GET. Turning it back on reverts to the original state. This only happens with shift, no other modifier keys.